# Can I pack both floats and ints into the same array buffer?

Tags: opengl, glsl

...because the floats seem to be coming out fine, but there's something wrong with the ints.

Essentially I have a struct called "BlockInstance" which holds a `vec3` and an `int`. I've got an array of these BlockInstances which I buffer like so (translating from C# to C for clarity):

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(BlockInstance)*numBlocks, blockData, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(3,3,GL_FLOAT,false,16,0);
glVertexAttribPointer(4,1,GL_INT,false,16,12);
glVertexAttribDivisor(3,1);
glVertexAttribDivisor(4,1);
```

And my vertex shader looks like this:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 TexCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 Normal;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 Translation;
layout (location = 4) in int TexIndex;

uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;

out vec2 TexCoord0;

void main()
{
    mat4 trans = mat4(
        1,0,0,0,
        0,1,0,0,
        0,0,1,0,
        Translation.x,Translation.y,Translation.z,1);
    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * trans * vec4(Position, 1.0);
    TexCoord0 = vec2(TexCoord.x+TexIndex,TexCoord.y)/16;
}
```

When I replace `TexIndex` on the last line of my GLSL shader with a constant like 0, 1, or 2, my textures come out fine, but if I leave it like it is, they come out all mangled, so there must be something wrong with the number, right? But I don't know what it's coming out as so it's hard to debug.

I've looked at my array of BlockInstances, and they're all set to 1,2, or 19 so I don't think my input is wrong...

What else could it be?

---

Note that I'm using a sprite map texture where each of the tiles is 16x16 px but my TexCoords are in the range 0-1, so I add a whole number to it to choose which tile, and then divide it by 16 (the map is also 16x16 tiles) to put it back into the proper range. The idea is I'll replace that last line with

```
TexCoord0 = vec2(TexCoord.x+(TexIndex%16),TexCoord.y+(TexIndex/16))/16;
```

-- GLSL does integer math, right? An int divided by an int will come out as whole number?

---

If I try this:

```
TexCoord0 = vec2(TexCoord.x+(TexIndex%16),TexCoord.y)/16;
```

The texture looks fine, but it's not using the right sprite. (Looks to be using the first sprite)

If I do this:

```
TexCoord0 = vec2(TexCoord.x+(TexIndex%16),TexCoord.y+(TexIndex/16))/16;
```

It comes out all white. This leads me to believe that `TexIndex` is coming out to be a very large number (bigger than 256 anyway) and that it's probably a multiple of 16.

Comment: "GLSL does integer math, right? An int divided by an int will come out as whole number?" Yes.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks! Just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
layout (location = 4) in int TexIndex;
```

There's your problem.

[`glVertexAttribPointer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttribPointer) is used to send data that will be converted to *floating-point* values. It's used to feed floating-point attributes. Passing integers is possible, but those integers are converted to floats, because that's what `glVertexAttribPointer` is for.

What you need is `glVertexAttribIPointer` (notice the **I**). This is used for providing signed and unsigned integer data.

So if you declare a vertex shader input as a `float` or some non-prefixed `vec`, you use `glVertexAttribPointer` to feed it. If you declare the input as `int`, `uint`, `ivec` or `uvec`, then you use `glVertexAttribIPointer`.

Comment: Excellent! Works now. Wouldn't have thought of that. The `VertexAttribPointerType` enum in OpenTK has types for Int, so I figured the function would accept an Int. Apparently not!

Comment: @Mark: The function accepts an int just fine. It simply expects to convert it to a *float* for consumption by GLSL. That is, it expects you to use `float` or `vec` types for the attribute. What you're trying to do is pass an integer as an *integer*, not to int-to-float conversion. That requires using `IPointer`, rather than `Pointer`.